# check characters are available or not in array

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have two `variables` such as below

```
$string1 = array('A','b','c');
$string2 = 'bAcdadbcliek'
```

need to check all the characters from `string1` is presents in `string2` or not in php and values are dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just wait for someone who will write code for you?

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for your attention, i try using `preg_match_all` but i dont know how to add this array into `preg_match_all`

Comment: With `implode` i suppose?

Comment: can i used that `implode` results direct as pattern??

Comment: Surely, you can

Comment: Does case sensitivity matter, will `a` match with `A` or not?

Comment: @Qirel yes it matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str_split` and `array_intersect`

```
    <?php

    $string1 = array('A','b','c');
    $string2 = 'bAcdadbcliek';

    $new = str_split($string2);

    $new_2 = array_intersect($string1,$new);

    if(count($new_2)==count($string1))
    {
       echo "all matched";   
    }
    else
    {
      echo "not ";   
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: but this case not given proper solution because any value not another string that time give not. suppose new string is $string1 = array('A','b','c','kl'); what to do in this case

Comment: *'all' the characters from string1 is presents in string2 or not* @WaseemAhmad

Comment: yes you are right but next time string is $string1 = array('A','b','c','kl'); what to do in this case. again write hole program

Comment: op doesn't mention that this kind of *array('A','b','c','kl');* array format . don't imagine yourself @WaseemAhmad

Answer (score 1):

try This

```
<?php
    $string1 = array('A','b','c','2');
    $string2 = 'bAcdadbcliek';
    foreach($string1 as $newstring)
    {
        $finalval=strrchr($string2,$newstring);
        if($finalval!="")
        {
        echo $newstring." ---: Available in given String<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo $newstring." ---: Not Available in given String<br/>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return a boolean true/false if all values are matched. It is case-sensitive.

Basically, split `$string2` into an array and intersect it, match the count of that against the count of `$string1` (which is an array, not a string by the way). If the count is equal, everything was found.

```
$string1 = array('A','b','c');
$string2 = 'bAcdadbcliek';

function match_string(string $string, array $match_values) {
    if (count(array_intersect(str_split($string), $match_values)) == count($match_values))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/cnUp2)